# Find counts from third level of nested array document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need to find count where status is `'a'` along with total no of element in element in array `'Y'` in a single query where `'X'` and `'Y'` are nested array of documents.

Collection is similar as follow:

```
{
   X: [
    {
       Y:[
          {
            STATUS: 'a' 
          },
          {
            STATUS: 'a' 
          },
          {
            STATUS: 'b' 
          }
         ]
    } 
    ]
}
```

A single mongodb query to find count of status `'a'` and total no of element in array `'Y'`.

Required results are counts of `'a'` which is `2` and total no of element in `'Y'` which is `3`.

Comment: Could you post the JSON output

Comment: i am not able to share doc json for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to transform an array and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to check if status is equal to `"a"`. [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) gives you the number of elements in array. Try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            X: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$X",
                    as: "xx",
                    in: {
                        Y: {
                            total: { $size: "$$xx.Y" },
                            a: { $size: { $filter: { input: "$$xx.Y", as: "yy", cond: { $eq: [ "$$yy.STATUS", "a" ] }  } } }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Result : [ { Y: { total: 3, a: 0 } }, { Y: { total: 3, a: 0 } } ]    Here 'a' should be 2

Comment: @Jitendra looks like it works correctly on your sample data, try: https://mongoplayground.net/p/jAwDNIyZUJ_

Comment: could you please helps me out in one another scenario here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889627/find-sum-of-status-in-nested-array-of-document-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation

First use [**`$map`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to loop over the `X` array and then use [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to remove unmatched elements.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "X": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$X",
        "as": "x",
        "in": {
          "aCount": {
            "$size": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$$x.Y",
                "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.STATUS", "a"] }
              }
            }
          },
          "allCount": { "$size": "$$x.Y" }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```