# Find sum of status in nested array of document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

In the below document structure I need to find total number of element in array 'X' and total counts of status 'a' in 'X'.

```
 [
      {
        X: [
          {
            Y: [
              {
                STATUS: "a"
              },
              {
                STATUS: "b"
              },
              {
                STATUS: "c"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            Y: [
              {
                STATUS: "a"
              },
              {
                STATUS: "b"
              },
              {
                STATUS: "c"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

here the required result would be total no of element in 'X' is 2 and total no of status 'a' inside 'X' is 2.

In tried but not able to get exact data in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) to get the length of array and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to apply STATUS `a` condition. Then you can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to simply sum all `a` for `X` array. Try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            total_a: { 
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$X",
                    initialValue: 0,
                    in: {
                        $add: [ "$$value", 
                            { $size: { $filter: { input: "$$this.Y", as: "yy", cond: { $eq: [ "$$yy.STATUS", "a" ] } } } } 
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            total_X: { $size: "$X" }
        }
    }
])
```

Playground [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6q2nVbWC0g-)